# Online charting with Xively (cosm replacement)

Tags: xively

Maybe I'm missing something obvious on the website, but I can't find any part of the new Xively website that provides any graphing capabilities for my feeds except for the 'feed url', but this is stuck at a 6 hour view. I'm particularly interested in week/day/hour views, and being able to compare channels with each other (I'm trying to tune my control algorithms)

Are we expected to be providing our own web front-ends on this platform? Seems to me that this isn't something that many developers will care about too much to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is 100% what you are looking for, but check out http://open.sen.se/

On open.sen.se you can get different type of graphs and embed them into your web page.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar digging, and come up with nothing.

I've already begun planning to implement my own solution for our little system. The change in interface has made what was once valuable almost unusable.

Comment: There will be improvements to the graphing pretty soon

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same. I've now moved my feeds to a fully home-grown system based around rrdtool.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. Since last Tuesday at 8 AM I have lost all graphs except 6 hour. I now have to do a GET to pull my old data and plot it in Excel. This has been a huge step backwards

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.  Make sure you know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to do online plots using the old API (see below), but I guess it's only a question of time until this feature will be gone. The API works with old (COSM) and new (Xively) streams.

I fully agree that this "new COSM" is a step back. Especially since I have not found a suitable way to code such a solution myself.

https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/**FEED-ID**/datastreams/**STREAM-ID**.png?colour=%23ff0000&stroke_size=1&show_axis_labels=true&detailed_grid=false&width=610&height=285&duration=36hours&scale=manual&min=18&max=33

Answer (score 0):

A search on Github resulted many options, including XivelyPlot, xively-angular-js-demo and offcial xively.github.io/xively-js/.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the Xively channel visualization tool. It's open source and you can host your own copy of it on GitHub pages for free. It's also a great example of the power of XivelyJS.

http://xively.github.io/channel-viz/

and the Github repo: https://github.com/xively/channel-viz